# Custom app: unhandledRejection: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm using getInitialProps in my _app.js:

```
import App from "next/app";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}

MyApp.getInitialProps = async ({ Component, ctx }) => {
  const appContext = App.getInitialProps(ctx);
  let pageProps = {};
  if (Component.getInitialProps)
    pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps(ctx);

  return { pageProps };
};

export default MyApp;
```

But getting the error

```
unhandledRejection: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')
```

The app still compiles successfully and the error is shown inside the terminal.
To reproduce it, you would only need to create a new nextjs app, and add the getInitialProps function

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the error. Could you provide a codesandbox or similar where the issue occurs?

Comment: That being said, there's no need to call `Component.getInitialProps`. `App.getInitialProps(ctx)` will call the current page's `getInitialProps` (if present) and return its `props` value. See the commented example at https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for your help, I'm trying without Component.getInitialProps, but it seems that the line "const appContext = App.getInitialProps(ctx);" is what causing the issue. If I await this, the app immediately breaks. This is very strange as this is exactly what is in the docs, and my next js is updated to 12. Is there anything else you think I could try? Thanks in advance

Comment: I found the problem, I should not do object destructuring, thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

I didn't follow the docs, the problem was with the destructuring I did, you need to receive the whole context object for App.getInitialProps

```
MyApp.getInitialProps = async (context) => {
...
```